# Can anyone help me to solve this problem with recursion?

Tags: c, function, recursion, chess

The problem is: There's 2 horse, white and black, they move like the way horse move in a normal chess game. Our objective is to find out if the black and white horse can meet each other (have the same location). There will be a limit for each horse to move.

-The user first must input the amount of test case.

-The second user input is the starting coordinates of the black horse ex: A1 and starting coordinates for the white horse ex: H8.

-The final user input is the limitation for each horse to move. for example if the user input 3 then each white and black horse has 3 chances to move.

-The output will be "YES" or "NO" >>>> YES if black and white can meet, NO if they cant

I was asked to solve this problem with recursion, but I'm stuck.

Here's some example:

**Input:**

**2** (amount of cases)

**A1 H8** (coordinates)

**3** (limit moves)

**A1 H8** (coordinates of the second case)

**1** (limit moves of the second case)

**Output:**

**Case #1: YES**

**Case #2: NO**

Can anyone spot the problem or the logic flaw..

```
#include <stdio.h>

int counter=0;
int count[10][10] = {{}};
void moveblack(int black_x,int black_y,int limitblack,int map[10][10],int limit){
//  printf("\n%d,%d\n",black_x,black_y);
//  printf("\n%d\n",limitblack);
//  limitblack++;

    if(limitblack > limit){
        limitblack =0;
        return;
    }
    count[black_y][black_x]++;
    map[black_y][black_x] = 1;
    if(black_x > 8 || black_y > 8 || black_x < 1 || black_y < 1){
        return;
    }
    else{
        //BLACK MOVE
        if(map[black_y+2][black_x+1] == 0){
            moveblack(black_x+1,black_y+2,limitblack+1,map,limit);  
        }
        if(map[black_y+2][black_x-1] == 0){
            moveblack(black_x-1,black_y+2,limitblack+1,map,limit);  
        }
        if(map[black_y-2][black_x+1] == 0){
            moveblack(black_x+1,black_y-2,limitblack+1,map,limit);  
        }   
        if(map[black_y-2][black_x-1] == 0){
            moveblack(black_x-1,black_y-2,limitblack+1,map,limit);  
        }
        if(map[black_y+1][black_x+2] == 0){
            moveblack(black_x+2,black_y+1,limitblack+1,map,limit);  
        }
        if(map[black_y+1][black_x-2] == 0) {
            moveblack(black_x-2,black_y+1,limitblack+1,map,limit);  
        }
        if(map[black_y-1][black_x+2] == 0){
            moveblack(black_x+2,black_y-1,limitblack+1,map,limit);  
        }   
        if(map[black_y-1][black_x-2] == 0){
            moveblack(black_x-2,black_y-1,limitblack+1,map,limit);  
        }
    }   
}
void movewhite(int white_x, int white_y,int limitwhite,int map[10][10],int limit){
//  limitwhite++;
    count[white_y][white_x]++;
    map[white_y][white_x] = 1;
    if(white_x > 8 || white_y > 8 || white_x < 1 || white_y < 1 ){
        return;
    }
    if(limitwhite > limit){
        limitwhite =0;
        return;
    }
    else{
        //WHITE MOVE
        if(map[white_y+2][white_x+1]==0){
            movewhite(white_x+1,white_y+2,limitwhite+1,map,limit);
        }
        if(map[white_y+2][white_x-1]==0){
            movewhite(white_x-1,white_y+2,limitwhite+1,map,limit);
        }   
        if(map[white_y-2][white_x+1]==0){
            movewhite(white_x+1,white_y-2,limitwhite+1,map,limit);
        }   
        if(map[white_y-2][white_x-1]==0){
            movewhite(white_x-1,white_y-2,limitwhite+1,map,limit);
        }   
        if(map[white_y+1][white_x+2]==0){
            movewhite(white_x+2,white_y+1,limitwhite+1,map,limit);
        }   
        if(map[white_y+1][white_x-2]==0){
            movewhite(white_x-2,white_y+1,limitwhite+1,map,limit);
        }   
        if(map[white_y-1][white_x+2]==0){
            movewhite(white_x+2,white_y-1,limitwhite+1,map,limit);
        }   
        if(map[white_y-1][white_x-2]==0){
            movewhite(white_x-2,white_y-1,limitwhite+1,map,limit);
        }               
    }   
}
int main()
{
    int tc;
    scanf("%d",&tc); // amount of test case
    for(int t=1;t<=tc;t++){
        int limit,map[10][10]={{}};
        scanf("%d",&limit); // amount of limit each horse have
        int limitblack = 0, limitwhite = 0;
        char black[3],white[3];
        int black1,white1;
        int black_x,black_y,white_x,white_y;
        getchar();
        scanf("%s %s",&black,&white); //coordinates ex A1 H8 or G6 B5 
        black_x = black[0] - ('A'-1); // scale 1-8
    //  printf("\n%d\n",black_x);
        black_y = (black[1]-'0');
    //  printf("\n%d\n",black_y);
        white_x = white[0] - ('A'-1); // scale 1-8
        white_y = (white[1]-'0');
//      printf("%d,%d\n",black_x,black_y);
//      printf("%d,%d\n",white_x,white_y);
         //Set Chess board as 0, prevent revisiting in recursion
        for(int i=8;i>=1;i--){
            for(int j=1;j<=8;j++){
                map[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
        //CHECK
//      for(int i=8;i>=1;i--){
//          for(int j=1;j<=8;j++){
//              if(i==black_x && j==black_y){
//                  printf("B");
//              }
//              else if(i==white_x && j==white_y){
//                  printf("W");
//              } else {
//                  printf("%d",map[i][j]);
//              }
//              
//          }
//          printf("\n");
//      }       
        moveblack(black_x,black_y,limitblack,map,limit);
        movewhite(white_x,white_y,limitwhite,map,limit);

        for(int i=1;i<=8;i++){
            for(int j=1;j<=8;j++){
                if(count[i][j]>=2){
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        }

        if(counter > 0){
            printf("Case #%d: YES\n",t);
        } 
        else if (counter == 0) {
            printf("Case #%d: NO\n",t);
        }
        counter=0;  
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you edit the question to give some example input, what you get, and what you expect? Please don't put it in a comment.

Comment: is it clear now?

Comment: I'd still like some example input. What are you inputting when you run the program? What input gets you 33425242?

Comment: there, gave example input and output

Comment: Please see [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest)

Comment: oh yes, im sorry, i didnt know the rule, i wont do it again. sorry im new to stackoverflow

Comment: You're fine. A lot of new people don't know the rule. We need to find a better way to show people.

Comment: Why a 10x10 board?  If one is attempting a border, I'd expect a 12x12 board.  I suspect code indexes out of range from time-to-time.

Answer (score 1):

You are not updating `limit_black` `limit_white` while making the next recursion call.

```
moveblack(black_x+1,black_y+2,limitblack,map,limit);
//....
```

should be: **limitblack+1**

```
moveblack(black_x+1,black_y+2,limitblack+1,map,limit);
// update other calls accordingly.
```

as in the base case you are comparing `limitblack/limitWhite` with `limit` that should prevent the infinite recursion.

```
if(limitwhite > limit){
        limitwhite =0;
        return;
}
```

You can also move this at the beginning of the recursion.

> Can anyone spot the problem or the logic flaw..

Yes there are several logic flaw in your implementation. 
First of all: You are using `count` array to check if that two horses visited the same index. **What if same black_horse visit that index twice/multiple time.**

Second: Your recursion is not carrying the exact visited stages in the next move. You should pass the referent instead of pass by value.

should be:

```
void moveblack(int black_x,int black_y,int limitblack,(--> pointer of that map array)int map[10][10],int limit)
```

also, index checking is not correct: 
if `white_y=1` and `white_x=1`

```
 map[white_y-1][white_x-2]==0
```

This will create segmentation fault.

There are also other flaws. But for now I guess that's enough.

Comment: your solution stops the infinite loop, there's some test case that is correct and but some are still wrong. I think there's a problem within the recursion?? do you spot any logic flaw??

Comment: there's a problem each time u do the first test case, but the second test case will be okay. can u help me to find the logic flaw on this?

Comment: @ArdianDanny I've added some cases. check these.